# Application to Automatically Free Modified Memory

Tags: windows-7, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Is there a Windows application or script that can free `modified memory` belonging to a given application.

I have tried **Flush File Cache** which is great as a big ol' hammer to clean out all `modified memory` but I need an application or script that can purge the memory that was allocated for a given application rather than the whole system.

#### System Specs

Windows 7 64 bit
8 GB RAM
12873 MB PageFile
SuperFetch Turned Off

#### A bit of background

I have created a **Node Webkit** application that processes lots of images, creating an image in memory and then discarding it. The initial implementation was leaking memory as I could see the commit size ballooning until Windows started to give out of memory warnings.

After a lot of rewrites the application's commit size stays around a good average and never really goes up, but what happens instead is the `modified memory` grows steadily (but much more slowly than before). This happens because the application allocates memory for the images and now deallocates them properly. Once the application stops processing the images but is still running, the `modified memory` slowly goes down back to normal without any intervention. If I run **Flush File Cache** with the `all` option it cleans out a whole host of *unused* memory without affecting my application (although the whole system slows down to a crawl momentarily as expected).

**Update**
Added a few screenshots to show what happens when 4 of them run simultaneously, nearing the end when `free memory` is critically low and `standby memory` is at around 1GB.
(apologies, can't post images yet because of my rep in this sub)

[image: standby near 1GB]

[image: ram usage after force quit]

Comment: Why do you believe this is required?  It shouldn't be required.  Most memory intensive applications do not do this.  Why do you believe you will get any performance boosts from flushing the modified memory?

Comment: I still get out of memory warnings, just much later. However when I purged the memory today the modified memory dropped from a 1GB down to 300MB and everything was still fine. I plan to run multiples of this application on the same machine so the memory will run out much faster and the stuff in modified memory is really not needed.

Comment: Are you running out of virtual memory or physical memory?  Because I actually have designed an application similar to yours ( based on the small description ) and didn't have this problem.

Comment: I think both, first the virtual then physical. I have added screenshots to show the state of the RAM whilst running the app and immediately after.

Comment: You have over 1GB free.  Have you tried to increase your page file?

Comment: so it looks like there's a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=439785) in Chromium when resizing the canvas so it's something I will have to work around, so the original question stands...

Answer (score 0):

The "out of memory" warnings are due to running out of commit limit. Windows does not have an error message for running out of physical memory (RAM).

To increase your commit limit, either add RAM or increase your pagefile size.

"Free" pages being "critically low" does not matter. "Standby" is part of "available"; it is just as "available" as "free" is. If you have 1 GB on the standby list then you have plenty of available RAM.

Comment: I know in theory that `free` and `standby` are supposed to be equal when it comes to `available` memory but what I have observed on my laptop and now some of our work machines is that performance is fine with the `free` memory gradually going to down to 0, but then as soon as it reaches low levels there is performance degradation even though there's plenty of `standby` memory available.

Comment: Sorry, but your conclusion is incorrect. Standby IS part of available and it is just as "available", just as quickly, as "free" is. Something else must be going on.
In any case, I will say again: Your "out of memory" warnings are NOT due to running out of RAM (either "standby", "free", or "available",  but rather to running out of commit limit. That is what the "out of memory" message means. It does not mean you are running low on RAM. 
How are you allocating the space that your program is using for these images? Your symptoms suggest that you are _not_ deallocating the memory in the best way.